# Как программно изменить colorPrimaryDark

Tags: android, android-themes

Как программно изменить colorPrimaryDark в активити, тема Theme.AppCompat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В рантайме нельзя программно изменять темы. Только подменять тему до `setContentView` в `onCreate` или `onCreateView` методом `setTheme(R.style.MyTheme)`. Там же можно задать тему, например, тулбару.

Можно попробовать воспользоваться библиотеками. Например, этой
https://github.com/negusoft/GreenMatter.
Хотя, скорее всего, она уже безнадежно устарела. Но, наверняка, есть подобные.

Comment: А если мне цвет заранее не известен, чтобы прописать в теме. А я передам его интэнтом. Как программно в теме выставить цвет, чтобы применить его до setContentView?

Comment: @msp стандартными средствами - никак. Посмотрите данные библиотеки: https://github.com/garretyoder/app-theme-engine, https://github.com/52inc/Scoops. Либо ту, которую я указал в ответе.

Answer (score 2):

Всю тему меняйте, если цвет заранее известен.

Если же цвет хотите динамически изменить, то никак.